# Route - Redirection (Next JS)

Tags: reactjs, express, routes, next.js

I am moving my website (PHP) to Next JS but I have a question regarding routes.

Currently I have this kind of routing (unique ID and slug from an API):

`www.website.com/section/id_slug-of-post`

And I manage some implementations, like:

`www.website.com/section/id => 301 to www.website.com/section/id_slug-of-post`

`www.website.com/section/id_slug-with-wrong-words => 301 to www.website.com/section/id_slug-of-post`

`www.website.com/section/wrong-id => 301 to www.website.com/section`

Can I do the same thing with Next JS or shall I use Express JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A feature like this is currently being discussed in [this RFC](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14890) on the Next.js GitHub. However, there is also a way to do this using the `res.writeHead` method in [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)

```js
export const getServerSideProps = (ctx) => {
    ctx.res.writeHead(301, { Location: '/new/url' });
}
```

You could also redirect on the client side using the Router instance provided by next/router.